# FB connect and magento

Tags: magento, facebook, user-permissions

As a novice developer at best, I have been tasked with implementing Facebook connect with my Magento 1.4.1.1 website. I have read extensively online and don't find much help with my problem, and I see many people have the same issue so perhaps everyone can learn.

I inserted the SDK script into my header, set up my channel, and my Facebook app. Everything seems to work nicely right now, however I am lost on converting the Facebook login into an actual Magento login. I understand that my code speaks with Facebook and authorizes my website, But I don't understand how to pull user permissions into my Magento database and store the information. Currently you click the "Login with Facebook" button, it pops up asking for the permissions. I don't know how to save this information to my database and allow the user to connect and login successfully.

I think I may need to add some more code somewhere telling Magento how to store this information?

Any advice or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use free extension [Facebook Connect and Like Free](http://store.belvg.com/free-extensions/facebook-connect-and-like-free.html) from BelVG company.

Comment: You can use this extension compitible on Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 so some changes on file http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/facebook-connect-and-like-free-compitible-1-8-1-0/

Comment: Here is a paid option which can allow you to let your customers login with Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo or Gamil.

http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/social-facebook-twitter-login-extension.html